# jboss rich dataTable wrong data

Tags: jboss, seam, richdatatable

```
   <rich:dataTable id="companyList" var="company"
    value="#{companyList.resultList}" 
rowClasses="odd-row, even-row"
    rendered="#{not empty companyList.resultList}">
    <rich:column width="25px" style="text-align:center;">
    <f:facet name="header">#{messages.Edit}</f:facet>
    <a4j:commandLink reRender="companyPanel"
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('companyPanel')}.show()"
    style="align: center;">                                     <f:setPropertyActionListener target=
"#{companyHome.instance}" 
    value="#{company}" />
    <rich:toolTip value="#{messages.Edit}" />
    </a4j:commandLink>
    </rich:column>
    <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
#{messages.companyName}</f:facet>
    #{company.companyName}
     </h:column>
    </rich:dataTable>
```

Hi I have some problem my rich datatable. All operation work normally , I search some data in dataTable ,I get true list in datatable but, If I try to update some data in column , wrong instance coming. Forexample , I choose banana which name is my data , but it brings before searching data not bring banana. I do not understand why. Sorry my english.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but, have you tried this

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{companyHome.id}" value="#{company.id}" />
```

instead of

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{companyHome.instance}" value="#{company}" />
```